# Having `f =` move to either => or ⇒

Tags: scala, vim

I edit a lot of Scala code in Vim, which means I hit `f =` a lot, as I head to the RHS of a case statement (or whatever else):

```
case PatternMatch(a, b, c) => RHS Here
```

But Scala supports unicode characters, which means that a lot of people will use `⇒` instead of `=>` and that makes `f ...` a pain in the butt.  Does anyone know how if there's a way to make `f =` move to the next `=` or `⇒`, whichever comes first?

Comment: People seriously use `⇒` in code?

Comment: @bamboon Not directly, no.  But it's fairly common to use scalariform and do this kind of re-writing automatically, it makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding this to your vimrc:

```
nmap f= :call search('=\\|⇒')<CR>
```

That will alias (map) `f=` to a call to the search function that will jump to the next `=` or `⇒`.

Comment: Similarly, `nnoremap f= /⇒\\|=<cr>`

Comment: @Conner, true, but since I have `hlsearch` turned on that also highlights every = and ⇒ in the file for me.

Comment: Of course :)  I was spending my time trying to figure out how to customize `f` and friends, but this will do just dandy.  Thanks.

Comment: This is great.  Too bad it doesn't integrate well with `;` and other motions.

Comment: I suppose another option would be to have vim rewrite `⇒` as `=>` automatically when you open a file and then convert back to `⇒` when you close it. That's a quite intrusive though and would probably cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: If you want to have it behave more like `f` (stick to the current line), then use some of the optional parameters to `search()`:  `call search('=\|⇒', '', line('.'))`.  See `:help search()`.  It is not so convenient as `;`, but you can repeat with `@:` and then `@@`, which is probably no better than `f=`.

Answer (score 2):

[bundacia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2904734/bundacia)'s answer is the one you asked for. Another option is to use digraphs. You can type `⇒` in vim by typing `<C-k>=>` in insert mode. You can also use this digraph with the `f` command (e.g. `f<C-k>=>`). No need for mappings etc. though it may be somewhat inconvenient to type.

I prefer this solution since it preserves other operator pending commands such as `df=`, `cf=`, etc. and allows the use of `F`, `t`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but `f<c-k>=>` makes it easier to look for another character and `f`, `t` (etc) that char instead